# Excel formula to show data trends

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Is there a way to have excel look at the last three cells for each column (that contain data) and let me know if they are increasing / decreasing (trending) as I add new data for each week?

In the example below- E66, E67, E68 are not "trending", however F66, F67, and F68 are showing a decreasing trend.

[image]

Comment: are all columns has the last data in the same row? in which cell do you want to get the result? If two values are the same, and third one is bigger then it's "increasing"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `INDEX(E:E,MATCH(1E+99,E:E))` to find the last cell in the column with a number.

Then using that in an IF statement we get:

```
=IF(AND(INDEX(E:E,MATCH(1E+99,E:E)-2)>INDEX(E:E,MATCH(1E+99,E:E)-1),INDEX(E:E,MATCH(1E+99,E:E)-1)>INDEX(E:E,MATCH(1E+99,E:E))),"Descending",IF(AND(INDEX(E:E,MATCH(1E+99,E:E)-2)<INDEX(E:E,MATCH(1E+99,E:E)-1),INDEX(E:E,MATCH(1E+99,E:E)-1)<INDEX(E:E,MATCH(1E+99,E:E))),"Ascending","No Trend"))
```

This dynamic.  No matter the position of the last three cells with numbers in each column it will adjust accordingly.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response and the perfect solution!  It works great!